# CSS positioning issues

Tags: css, positioning

I'm trying to, of course, build something in HTML.

However, I am running into some serious issues with positioning!

I'm trying to get elements in the website to be centered, but I cannot do that without sacrificing (somehow) controls such as z-index, and width on those elements -- In some cases, vice versa.

Theoretically, I should be able to make something be centered, set it's width, AND set it's Z index all at once.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Is there a specific example that you're trying to work with, or are you just asking if it's possible to set all of those attributes at once?

Comment: @Lord Torgamus -- Yes, I'm asking if it is possible, and how, to set all of those attributes at once. 
P.S. Awesome name

Comment: nice, I'm glad someone else gets it. I was basically writing what Andrew had, but he beat me to it; comment back if it doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To center something, set it's margins to `auto`. To set an objects width, set it's `width`, to set an object's z-index, set it's position to `relative` to maintain it's centreness, and set it's z-index accordingly.

```
div {
    width:40%;
    position:relative;
    z-index:5;
    margin:auto;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/wDzkd/

Comment: Hi, Andrew! Thanks so much for the reply. I'll see how it works.